# Remove last word from whole string

Tags: ruby

I have following string

```
2014-04-29T06-19-20_17368f93ce02e18f278ae22d248e7d0692db3f54d2409_1088x288.mp4.uploaded
```

I want to remove the last `.uploaded` word from this whole string .

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.sub` to replace `.uploaded` with nothing:

```
str='2014-04-29T06-19-20_17368f93ce02e18f278ae22d248e7d0692db3f54d2409_1088x288.mp4.uploaded'
str.sub! '.uploaded', ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer of this:

```
"2014-04-29T06-19-20_17368f93ce02e18f278ae22d248e7d0692db3f54d2409_1088x288.mp4.uploaded".split(".uploaded").first
```

It delete the last word from the given string

o/p:

```
2014-04-29T06-19-20_17368f93ce02e18f278ae22d248e7d0692db3f54d2409_1088x288.mp4
```